# Sending form data via AJAX and populating a div with the results

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to make an AJAX call to submit the data from the "Data" div and use the results to populate the Results div.

At this point, it doesn't call the AJAX on a submit. Should I even use html.BeginForm() if I don't want to submit that way?

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '@Url.Content("~/ControllerName/ActionName")',
data: ModelName,
success: function(result) {
$('#Results').data = result;
}});*@



@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
  <div id="Data">

  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID, new SelectList(Model.Stuff, "ID", "Name"), "Choose")
   //more dropdown lists
  

<input name="SubmitButton" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit"/>

  </div>
 }


 <div id="Results">

   @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.Sum)

 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/XQdmK1

Controller/View Models

```
public class Stuff
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class JohnViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public IList<Stuff> Stuff { get; set; }
    public int Sum { get; set; }
}
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index18()
    {
        var stuff1 = new Stuff { ID = 1, Name = "Name1" };
        var stuff2 = new Stuff { ID = 2, Name = "Name2" };
        var stuff3 = new Stuff { ID = 3, Name = "Name3" };
        var viewModel = new JohnViewModel();
        viewModel.Sum = 27;
        viewModel.Stuff = new List<Stuff>();
        viewModel.Stuff.Add(stuff1);
        viewModel.Stuff.Add(stuff2);
        viewModel.Stuff.Add(stuff3);
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult JohnUpdate(string myvar)
    {
        var q = myvar;
        return Json(q, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View

```
@model WebApplication2.Controllers.JohnViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index18</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#Submit").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/home/JohnUpdate',
                    type: "POST",
                    //dataType: "JSON",
                    data: { myvar: $("#selector option:selected").text() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#Results").text(data);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                        alert(thrownError);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Data">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID, new SelectList(Model.Stuff, "ID", "Name"), "Choose", new { id = "selector" })
        @*more dropdown lists*@
        <input name="SubmitButton" type="button" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
    <div id="Results">
        @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.Sum)
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!! I noticed that it's returning the entire HTML of the 2nd div.  How would I get that to render and not just print out the text of the HTML? :)

Comment: If you do a view page, after clicking on the submit button the second div looks like this  <div id="Results">
            27
        </div>  so the content "27" is getting overwritten in the javascript to "Name2", for example, and the view source only shows the original DOM.  $("#Results").text(data);  is adding text within div.  Like <div>Name1</div>.  Please ask me, in case I am not understanding what you need.

Comment: I figured it out.  It should be  $("#Results").html(data);    Thanks for your help!